# Python: write function return value to output file

Tags: python, file-io, io

I have 5 input files. I'm reading the targets & arrays from the 2nd & 3rd lines. I have 2sum function. I need to output the function's returned value(s) and output them to 5 output files.

I know my functions correct. I print it out just fine.
I know I'm reading 5 input files & creating & writing to 5 output files.

What I can't figure out is how to write my return value(s) from the `twoSum` function ***INTO*** the output function.

```
def twoSum(arr, target):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i, len(arr)):
            curr = arr[i] + arr[j]
            if arr[i]*2 == target:
                return [i, i]
                return answer
            if curr == target:
                return [i, j]
```

Read 5 files

```
inPrefix = "in"
outPrefix = "out"
for i in range(1, 6):
    inFile = inPrefix + str(i) + ".txt"
    with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
        fileLines = f.readlines()
        target = fileLines[1]
        arr = fileLines[2]
```

***how do i get write twoSum's value to output file?***

```
???????
```

Output to 5 files

```
    outFile = outPrefix + str(i) + ".txt"
    with open(outFile, 'a') as f:
        f.write(target) #just a test to make sure I'm writing successfully
        f.write(arr)    #just a test to make sure I'm writing successfully
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what processedOutput is set to before you write it to the output file? It might be helpful to test writing it to a single file outside of the main loop to isolate the bug.

Comment: it's not set to anything. it's created at `processedOutput = twoSum(arr, target)`. I think one problem i have is that when I read the first two lines and assign them to variables, i think they become strings? this part `target = fileLines[1] arr = fileLines[2]`so the function needs them to be integers??

Comment: No what I meant was what is the result of twoSum(), which is caught in the variable processedOutput

Comment: the result, normally (I/O aside), is an array of two numbers. the function finds two numbers in a list of nuts that add up to the target.

Comment: f.write() only accepts strings. You'll get a TypeError otherwise. You'll need to convert them before writing to file, even if it's a temporary copy for IO.

Comment: i just updated my original question's code to show where I'm lost. i get what you're saying in theory, but still unsure if the problem needs to be fixed in my original function or manipulated somehow outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Two things that come to mind:

1. open the file in `wt` mode (Write Text).
2. `processedOutput` appears to be a list. When you write to a file, you need write a string. Are you wanting a CSV style output of those values ? or just a line of spaced out values ? The simplest way here, would be something like: `" ".join(processedOutput)`. That will separate all the items in your processedOut list by a string.

Comment: but i thought it had to 'a' (append mode) because the output files don't exist yet. they have to be created by running the program?

Comment: ah, but if i'm running a math equation (adding numbers, finding a sum etc) how does that work? is the function outside the I/O and same return value to global variable ("answer"), I call it inbetween I & O and then convert "answer" to str and then write `str(answer)` to the output file?